# Clipboard.js is not copying

Tags: javascript, flask

I followed this: https://jsfiddle.net/gevorgha/fbeof421/

This is my html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
    [...]    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/clipboard.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script>
            new Clipboard('.btn');
        </script>

    <body>



    <!-- Target -->
    <div id="bar">Mussum ipsum cacilds...</div>

    <!-- Trigger -->
    <button class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#bar">
    Copy to clipboard
</button>



      </body>
    </html>
```

I don't have any problem with

```
"{{ url_for('static', filename='js/clipboard.min.js') }}"
```

I have this error in my browser console:

```
clipboard.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at o (clipboard.min.js:7)
    at c (clipboard.min.js:7)
    at o (clipboard.min.js:7)
    at e.t [as listenClick] (clipboard.min.js:7)
    at new e (clipboard.min.js:7)
    at (index):13
o   @   clipboard.min.js:7
c   @   clipboard.min.js:7
o   @   clipboard.min.js:7
t   @   clipboard.min.js:7
e   @   clipboard.min.js:7
(anonymous) @   (index):13
```

The jsfiddle example as it is works and not mine. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: It's a good habit to use unminified javascript files in the dev environment to help debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript needs the button to already be made before calling it. Since the head is the first part of the html code that is done, it means that it tries to call a button that has not yet been created.

Placing the script where you call the button at the bottom of the body will make sure that the button is made before the script tries to call it.
Hope it helps.